# why query giving 0 rows

Tags: mysql, sql-server

Query1

```
    SELECT SessionInfo.IVRSessionInfoID         
    FROM SessionInfo 
     WHERE SessionCallTime BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-08-01 00:00:00') 
        AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('2013-08-01 23:59:59')
    ORDER BY SessionInfo.SessionCallTime DESC;
```

Query2

```
          SELECT SessionInfo.IVRSessionInfoID         
          FROM SessionInfo 
         WHERE (SessionInfo.SessionCallTime BETWEEN '2013-08-01 00:00:00'
                                         AND  '2013-08-01 23:59:59')
          ORDER BY SessionInfo.SessionCallTime DESC;
```

what is the diffrence why first query gives 0 rows
second query gives records

in this tables 20000 rows betwqeen this two dates

table schema

```
    CREATE TABLE `SessionInfo` (
    `IVRSessionInfoID` bigint(8) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `SessionCallTime` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
   `MGServerIP` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
   `MGServerPort` smallint(2) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '5060',
    `SessionUniqueID` varchar(64) NOT NULL,
   `ANI` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `CountryID` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `CountryStateAreaID` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `AccessNumberProviderLogID` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
 `AccessNumberLogID` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
    `AccessRestrictionLogID` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`SubscriberCardID` bigint(8) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `SessionDuration` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
`SessionRNDDuration` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
 `TotalCharge` decimal(15,6) unsigned NOT NULL,
`RuleSetLogID` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`RuleSetChargeInfoLogID` int(4) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
`RuleSetRNDDuration` int(4) unsigned NOT NULL,
`RuleSetTotalCharge` decimal(15,6) unsigned NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`IVRSessionInfoID`),
   UNIQUE KEY `UNIQUE` (`SessionUniqueID`),
   KEY `SessionCallTime` (`SessionCallTime`),
   KEY `ANI` (`ANI`),
   KEY `CountryID` (`CountryID`),
    KEY `CountryStateAreaID` (`CountryStateAreaID`),
  KEY `AccessNumberProviderLogID` (`AccessNumberProviderLogID`),
  KEY `AccessNumberLogID` (`AccessNumberLogID`),
   KEY `AccessRestrictionLogID` (`AccessRestrictionLogID`),
  KEY `SubscriberCardID` (`SubscriberCardID`),

   ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=22199955 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

Comment: You'll need to provide at least minimal table schema. Anyway I think this one is offtopic here.

Answer (score 3):

This question is likely better suited for DBA exchange...

...but my guess is because `UNIX_TIMESTAMP('anything')` returns and `int/decimal/number` and the `'2013-08-01 23:59:59'` is the format of some Database `DateTime` datatype.

.

EG: `SessionInfo.SessionCallTime` does not use a datatype that is compatible with `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`.